# App quits after deliberately not giving location permission

Tags: android, geolocation, android-permissions

This issue happens when I deliberately don't do anything when the permission request screen pops up, the app will just crash after a few seconds.

The permission requests pop up after transitioned from another activity (LoginActivity) to MapsActivity.

LoginActivity

```
if statement to check the validity
    if valid
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MapActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

MapActivity

```
...    
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    getLocationPermission();
    updateLocationUI();
    getDeviceLocation();
}

private void getLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: add crash log ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210530/115145

Comment: Add crash log explain what exactly you need and what happening. So someone can help you quickly.

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical There aren't any errors popping up on the Logcat.

Comment: @AjayMehta-Rlogical `at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityCompat.java:502)
        at com.turnitin_fyp.prezent.MapsActivityCurrentPlace.getLocationPermission(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java:166)
        at com.turnitin_fyp.prezent.MapsActivityCurrentPlace.updateLocationUI(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java:207)
        at com.turnitin_fyp.prezent.MapsActivityCurrentPlace.onRequestPermissionsResult(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java:189)`

Comment: What before "at.." should have Exception name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised how to solve this with a simpled solution lmao...
In my original code, I have onRequestPermissionResult() already btw.

MapActivity

```
private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            }
        }
    }
    updateLocationUI();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
...
getLocationPermission();
    if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
        updateLocationUI();
        getDeviceLocation();

    }
}
```

No more crashing now :)

Answer (score 0):

i am checking the permission this way and this is working properly try this :-

```
if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                    Log.e("Tag", "Camera and External storage Permission's are allowed");
                } else {
                    requestLocationPermission();
                }
```

this is the method checkLocationPermission:-

```
private boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this is request method for location:-

```
private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Have To Give Permission From Your Device Setting To go in Setting Please Click on Settings Button");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Go To Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1012);
        }
    }
```

and finally onRequestPermissionsResult:-

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You Have To Give Permission From Your Device Setting To go in Setting Please Click on Settings Button");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Go To Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }else{
          // do your stuff in case accept permission
        }

    }
```